# How to pass a generic List to a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, list, generics, crystal-reports

I try to `Print` a `List of objects` to `Crystal Report`. So I created a WPF Window as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace Winlease.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour EcheancierPrint.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EcheancierPrint : Window
    {
        List<T> ListToPrint = null;

        public EcheancierPrint(List<T> lst) : base()
        {
            ListToPrint = lst;
        }

        public EcheancierPrint()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load("../../Echeancier.rpt");
            rd.SetDataSource(ListToPrint);
        }
    }
}
```

This window is called from Click event handler of button in another window, here the code:

```
private void cmdPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EcheancierPrint pe = new EcheancierPrint(echeancier);
}
```

`Echeancier` is a `List of Object` called `Echeance`. The type **"T"** and The method **InitializeComponent** become underlined with red and are not accepted from WPF compiler. Same Behavior for instruction:

```
EcheancierPrint pe = new EcheancierPrint(echeancier);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is not a concrete type you must declare `EcheancierPrint` as generic type `EcheancierPrint<T>` but currently XAML does not support generics. (XAML 2009 does but not for compiled XAML).
Moreover in your case type is open generic type.

And do you really nedd to mix persentation objects (UI controls) with business objects?

Comment: The Echeance Business Object is defined in another DLL assembly called BLL. Now, i solved The problem of generic type by specifying the real type as follows :  public EcheancierPrint(List<Echeance> lst) : base()
        {
            ListToPrint = lst;
        }

Comment: about the InitializeComponent, it is underlined with red because i changed the namespace and i dont updated xaml file. Thank you